# How should I create variable x so that I can output the values (1,2), f(2,2), f(3,2), f(4,2),...,f(10,2)?

Tags: python, function, data-structures, lambda

Given the following lambda function,

```
f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
```

how should I create variable x so that I can output the values

```
f(1,2), f(2,2), f(3,2), f(4,2),...,f(10,2)?
```

I tried

```
a = [ (b,2) for b in range(1,11)]
f(a)
```

and it gives error lambda() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'.

I also tried

```
f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
a = [(i,2) for i in np.linspace(1, 10, 10)]
for j in a:
    f(j)
```

and it gives the same error lambda() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'.

How can we do this?

Comment: How would you plot it if it was a function with a single argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you lambda function accept 2 arguments you giving it a list of tuple.
using a for loop and * operator you can do something like that:

```
for tuple_ in a:
    print(f(*tuple_))
```

the "*" operator is called the unpacking operator more here [unpacking pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `f` with the arguments provided in each element of the list `a`:

```
f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2

a = [ (b,2) for b in range(1,11)]

for x,y in a:
  print(f(x,y))
```

[Try it on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AlphanumericCumbersomeInitialization)